# OpenCL AMD GPU compiler crash

Tags: crash, kernel, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I am working on a kernel that find intersections between ray and a triangle list, but (there is always a "but" ) i got some trouble using my opencl compiler indeed it crashes when I try to compile it.

I try to compile it on my CPU compiler and it compile well, but with my GPU compiler it crashes...

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
//---------------------------------DEFINES-------------------------------------  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

#define RAYON_SORTANT -1000  
#define RAYON_ENTRANT 1000  

#define MIN_LONGUEUR_RT 1.E-6f  

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
//---------------------------------CONTENT-------------------------------------  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

typedef struct s_CDPoint  
{  
    float x;  
    float y;  
    float z;  
} CDPoint;  

typedef struct s_TTriangle  
{  
    CDPoint            triangle_[3];  
    CDPoint            normal_;  
} TTriangle;  

typedef struct s_GridIntersection  
{  
    CDPoint         pos_;  
    float             distance_;  
    int                sensNormale_;  
    unsigned int    idTriangle_;  
} TGridIntersection;  

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
//---------------------------------MUTEX---------------------------------------  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

void GetSemaphor(__global int * semaphor)  
{  
   int occupied = atomic_xchg(semaphor, 1);  
   while(occupied > 0)  
   {  
     occupied = atomic_xchg(semaphor, 1);  
   }  
}  

void ReleaseSemaphor(__global int * semaphor)  
{  
   int prevVal = atomic_xchg(semaphor, 0);  
}  

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
//---------------------------------GEOMETRIE-----------------------------------  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

float dotProduct(const CDPoint* pA, const CDPoint* pB)  
{  
    return (pA->x * pB->x + pA->y * pB->y + pA->z * pB->z);  
}  

CDPoint crossProduct(const CDPoint* pA, const CDPoint* pB)  
{  
    CDPoint res;  

    res.x = pA->y * pB->z - pB->y * pA->z;  
    res.y = pA->z * pB->x - pB->z * pA->x;  
    res.z = pA->x * pB->y - pB->x * pA->y;  

    return res;  
}  

CDPoint soustraction(const CDPoint* pA, const CDPoint* pB)  
{  
    CDPoint res;  
    res.x = pA->x - pB->x;  
    res.y = pA->y - pB->y;  
    res.z = pA->z - pB->z;  
    return res;  
}  

CDPoint addition(const CDPoint* pA, const CDPoint* pB)  
{  
    CDPoint res;  
    res.x = pA->x + pB->x;  
    res.y = pA->y + pB->y;  
    res.z = pA->z + pB->z;  
    return res;  
}  

CDPoint homothetie(const CDPoint* pA, float val)  
{  
    CDPoint pnt;  
    pnt.x = pA->x * val;  
    pnt.y = pA->y * val;  
    pnt.z = pA->z * val;  
    return pnt;  
}  

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
//---------------------------------KERNEL--------------------------------------  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

__kernel void IntersectionTriangle(    __global const TTriangle* pTriangleListe,  
                            const unsigned int idxDebutTriangle,  
                            const unsigned int idxFin,  
                            __constant const CDPoint* pPointOrigine,  
                            __constant const CDPoint* pDir,  
                            __global int *nbInter,  
                            __global TGridIntersection* pResults    )  
{  
    __private unsigned int index = get_global_id(0) + idxDebutTriangle;  

    if (index > idxFin) return;  

    __global const TTriangle *pTriangle = &pTriangleListe[index];  
    __private float distance = 0.f;  

    // Côté du triangle et normale au plan  
    __private CDPoint edge1 = soustraction(&pTriangle->triangle_[1], &pTriangle->triangle_[0]);  
    __private CDPoint edge2 = soustraction(&pTriangle->triangle_[2], &pTriangle->triangle_[0]);  
    __private CDPoint pvec = crossProduct(pDir, &edge2);            // produit vectoriel  

    // Le rayon et le triangle sont il parallèle ?  
    __private float det = dotProduct(&edge1, &pvec);  
    if (det == 0.f)  
    {  
        return ;  
    }  
    __private float inv_det = 1.f / det;  

    // Distance origin t0  
    __private CDPoint tvec = soustraction(pPointOrigine, &pTriangle->triangle_[0]);  

    //Calculate u parameter and test bound  
    __private float u = (dotProduct(&tvec, &pvec)) * inv_det;  
    //The intersection lies outside of the triangle  
    if (u < -MIN_LONGUEUR_RT  
        || u > 1.f + MIN_LONGUEUR_RT)  
    {  
        return ;  
    }  

    u = max(u, 0.f);  

    //Prepare to test v parameter  
    __private CDPoint qvec = crossProduct(&tvec, &edge1);  

    //Calculate V parameter and test bound  
    __private float v = dotProduct(pDir, &qvec) * inv_det;  

    //The intersection lies outside of the triangle  
    if (v < -MIN_LONGUEUR_RT  
        || u + v  > 1.f + MIN_LONGUEUR_RT)  
    {  
        return ;  
    }  

    // Get distance  
    distance = dotProduct(&edge2, &qvec) * inv_det;  

    if (distance > -MIN_LONGUEUR_RT)  
    {  
        // We are using nbInter as semaphor index  
        GetSemaphor(nbInter);  

        __private int idxInter = *nbInter;  

        pResults[idxInter].distance_ = max(distance, 0.f);  

        // Intersection point  
        __private CDPoint vDir = homothetie(pDir, distance);  
        pResults[idxInter].pos_ = addition(pPointOrigine, &vDir);  

        // Get ray way  
        pResults[idxInter].sensNormale_ = dotProduct(&pTriangle->normal_, pDir) > 0.f ? RAYON_SORTANT : RAYON_ENTRANT;  

        // Triangle id  
        pResults[idxInter].idTriangle_ = index - idxDebutTriangle;  

        // inc nb inter  
        *nbInter = *nbInter + 1;  

        ReleaseSemaphor(nbInter);  
    }  

}
```

I notice that if I change "__global const TTriangle* pTriangleListe" by "const TTriangle* pTriangleListe" it compiles but it is not the code i want !

Exactly what I want to do, is to fill all triangles in "pTriangleListe", and with a uniform grid get indexes of triangles to check (idxDebutTriangle/idxFin). "pPointOrigine" is the ray origin and "pDir" the direction. "nbInter" and "pResults" are shared and will contains intersections (they are protected by the semaphor)

Here it is my openCL computer configuration :

```
Platform [0]
id      = 5339E7D8
profile     = FULL_PROFILE
version     = OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1445.5)
name    = AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
vendor  = Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
extensions = cl_khr_icd
                cl_khr_d3d10_sharing
                cl_khr_d3d11_sharing
                cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing
                cl_amd_event_callback
                cl_amd_offline_devices
                cl_amd_hsa




2 Devices detected
    Device [0]
        id                          = 010DFA00
        type                        = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
        name                        = Cedar
        vendor                      = Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
        driver version              = 1445.5 (VM)
        device version              = OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1445.5)
        profile                     = FULL_PROFILE
        max compute units           = 2
        max work items dimensions   = 3
        max work item sizes         = 128 / 128 / 128
        max work group size         = 128
        max clock frequency         = 650 MHz
        address_bits                = 32
        max mem alloc size          = 512 MB
        global mem size             = 1024 MB
        image support               = CL_TRUE
        max read image args         = 128
        max write image args        = 8
        2D image max size           = 16384 x 16384
        3D image max size           = 2048 x 2048 x 2048
        max samplers                = 16
        max parameter size          = 1024
        mem base addr align         = 2048
        min data type align size    = 128
        single fp config            = CL_FP_INF_NAN CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST CL_FP_ROUND_TO_ZERO CL_FP_ROUND_TO_INF CL_FP_FMA
        global mem cache type       = CL_NONE
        max constant buffer size    = 64 KB
        max constant args           = 8
        local mem type              = CL_LOCAL
        local mem size              = 32 KB
        error correction support    = CL_FALSE
        profiling timer resolution  = 1 ns
        endian little               = CL_TRUE
        available                   = CL_TRUE
        compiler available          = CL_TRUE
        execution capabilities      = CL_EXEC_KERNEL
        queue properties            = CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
        extensions                  = cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics
                                        cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics
                                        cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics
                                        cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics
                                        cl_khr_3d_image_writes
                                        cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
                                        cl_khr_gl_sharing
                                        cl_ext_atomic_counters_32
                                        cl_amd_device_attribute_query
                                        cl_amd_vec3
                                        cl_amd_printf
                                        cl_amd_media_ops
                                        cl_amd_media_ops2
                                        cl_amd_popcnt
                                        cl_khr_d3d10_sharing
                                        cl_khr_d3d11_sharing
                                        cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing
                                        cl_amd_image2d_from_buffer_read_only
                                        cl_khr_spir
                                        cl_khr_gl_event


    Device [1]  
        id                          = 03501CD0  
        type                        = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU    
        name                        =     Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2130 CPU @ 3.40GHz   
        vendor                      = GenuineIntel  
        driver version              = 1445.5 (sse2,avx)     
        device version              = OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1445.5)   
        profile                     = FULL_PROFILE  
        max compute units           = 4     
        max work items dimensions   = 3     
        max work item sizes         = 1024 / 1024 / 1024    
        max work group size         = 1024  
        max clock frequency         = 3392 MHz  
        address_bits                = 32    
        max mem alloc size          = 1024 MB   
        global mem size             = 2048 MB   
        image support               = CL_TRUE   
        max read image args         = 128   
        max write image args        = 8     
        2D image max size           = 8192 x 8192   
        3D image max size           = 2048 x 2048 x 2048    
        max samplers                = 16    
        max parameter size          = 4096  
        mem base addr align         = 1024  
        min data type align size    = 128   
        single fp config            = CL_FP_DENORM CL_FP_INF_NAN CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST CL_FP_ROUND_TO_ZERO CL_FP_ROUND_TO_INF CL_FP_FMA    
        global mem cache type       = CL_READ_WRITE_CACHE   
        global mem cacheline size   = 64    
        global mem cache size       = 32768     
        max constant buffer size    = 64 KB     
        max constant args           = 8     
        local mem type              = CL_GLOBAL     
        local mem size              = 32 KB     
        error correction support    = CL_FALSE  
        profiling timer resolution  = 301 ns    
        endian little               = CL_TRUE   
        available                   = CL_TRUE   
        compiler available          = CL_TRUE   
        execution capabilities      = CL_EXEC_KERNEL CL_EXEC_NATIVE_KERNEL  
        queue properties            = CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE     
        extensions                  = cl_khr_fp64   
                                        cl_amd_fp64     
                                        cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics    
                                        cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics    
                                        cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics     
                                        cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics     
                                        cl_khr_3d_image_writes  
                                        cl_khr_byte_addressable_store   
                                        cl_khr_gl_sharing   
                                        cl_ext_device_fission   
                                        cl_amd_device_attribute_query   
                                        cl_amd_vec3     
                                        cl_amd_printf   
                                        cl_amd_media_ops    
                                        cl_amd_media_ops2   
                                        cl_amd_popcnt   
                                        cl_khr_d3d10_sharing    
                                        cl_khr_spir     
                                        cl_amd_svm  
                                        cl_khr_gl_event
```

Thank you for reading !

Comment: I see you've already posted on AMD's forum. They'll eventually fix it :)

Comment: Yes but i am not sure what I want to do is possible... (with kernel)

Comment: I would start be commenting out the whole main function body (aka does nothing) then gradually uncomment until the compiler crashes. This should take you to the line or two that is causing the compiler to choke. I'd then suggest changing the code so it does the same thing but is semantically different, e.g. instead of using *pTriangle use pTriangleListe[index], etc. directly. Sadly, it is just experimentation :(

Comment: Yes good idea, i did it and i found a way to make my code compile, i just change kernel header by : __kernel void IntersectionTriangle( __constant const TTriangle* restrict pTriangleListe, const unsigned int idxDebutTriangle, const unsigned int idxFin, const CDPoint pointOrigine, const CDPoint direction,__global int *nbInter,__global TGridIntersection* pResults) . (remove pointer on "pointOrigine" and "direction"). That will do the job while waiting AMD will look to this crash, thanks !

Comment: If you post this info with your AMD post it'll probably help them.

Comment: For those who want to see the AMD forum's message : http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1305634